# 'unitOfWork parameter cannot be null' in Background Worker

Tags: c#, asynchronous, background-process, unit-of-work, aspnetboilerplate

I've started getting these errors. It was working perfectly on my previous server.

```
using System;
using Abp.Dependency;
using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using Abp.Threading.BackgroundWorkers;
using EMS.IPs;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using EMS.Contacts;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Abp.Domain.Uow;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EMS.EmailValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using KellermanSoftware.NetEmailValidation;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Transactions;

namespace EMS.BackgroundWorkers
{
    public class ContactValidationBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorkerBase, ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly IRepository<IP> _ipsRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Contact> _contactsRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager2;
        private readonly IRepository<Contact> _contactRepository;

        private BackgroundWorker bgworker = new BackgroundWorker();

        ActionBlock<ValidationObject> workerBlock;

        public ContactValidationBackgroundWorker(
            IRepository<IP> ipsRepository,
            IRepository<Contact> contactsRepository,
            IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,
            IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager2,
            IRepository<Contact> contactRepository)
        {
            _ipsRepository = ipsRepository;
            _contactsRepository = contactsRepository;
            _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
            _unitOfWorkManager2 = unitOfWorkManager2;
            _contactRepository = contactRepository;

            bgworker.DoWork += Worker;
        }

        public override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();
            bgworker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        public override void Stop()
        {
            bgworker.DoWork -= Worker;
        }

        public void Worker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
            {
                var contacts = _contactsRepository.GetAll().Where(x => !x.IsChecked);
                if (!contacts.Any())
                {
                    Logger.Debug("No contacts");
                    return;
                }

                workerBlock = new ActionBlock<ValidationObject>(
                  async (arg) => await Validate(arg),
                  new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                  {
                      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
                  });

                foreach (var contact in contacts)
                {
                    workerBlock.Post(new ValidationObject()
                    {
                        Contact = contact
                    });
                }

                unitOfWork.Complete();
            }

            Logger.Debug("End posting jobs to threads. Awaits results...");

            workerBlock.Complete();
            workerBlock.Completion.Wait();
        }

        public override void WaitToStop()
        {
            base.WaitToStop();
        }

        private async Task Validate(ValidationObject validationObject)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var contactUnitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager2.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
                {
                    Contact contact = validationObject.Contact;
                    contact.IsChecked = true;

                    await _contactRepository.UpdateAsync(contact);
                    await contactUnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ValidationResult
    {
        public ValidationResult()
        {
            IsValid = false;
            Message = "";
        }

        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValidationObject
    {
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It works inside background worker; it worked before. Now it doesn't. `Contact` object is not null.
It seems to ask me to add `unitOfWork` parameter to `Update` method. Please help me figure this out.

```
ERROR 2017-12-26 12:02:34,768 [14   ] orkers.ContactValidationBackgroundWorker - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: unitOfWork
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkExtensions.GetDbContext[TDbContext](IActiveUnitOfWork unitOfWork, Nullable`1 multiTenancySide)
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.Update(TEntity entity)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IRepository`2_Update_8.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformSyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IRepository`1Proxy_3.Update(Contact entity)
   at EMS.BackgroundWorkers.ContactValidationBackgroundWorker.<Validate>d__21.MoveNext() in /Users/grinay/Projects/EMSBackend/src/EMS.Application/BackgroundWorkers/ContactValidationBackgroundWorker.cs:line 329
```

**UPDATE1**

```
  ERROR 2017-12-27 05:31:34,500 [9    ] orkers.ContactValidationBackgroundWorker - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: unitOfWork
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkExtensions.GetDbContext[TDbContext](IActiveUnitOfWork unitOfWork, Nullable`1 multiTenancySide)
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IRepository`2_UpdateAsync_8.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformAsyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IRepository`1Proxy_3.UpdateAsync(Contact entity)
   at EMS.BackgroundWorkers.ContactValidationBackgroundWorker.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<<Validate>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(Func`1 action)
   at EMS.BackgroundWorkers.ContactValidationBackgroundWorker.Validate(ValidationObject validationObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `async` methods with `unitOfWork` like that in background worker.

Make the changes in these 5 lines:

```
public void Worker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    workerBlock = new ActionBlock<ValidationObject>(
      (arg) => Validate(arg), // This line #1
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
          MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
      });

    // ...
}

private void Validate(ValidationObject validationObject) // This line #2
{
    try
    {
        using (var contactUnitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager2.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            Contact contact = validationObject.Contact;
            contact.IsChecked = true;

            AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () => // This line #3
            {                               // This line #4
                await _contactRepository.UpdateAsync(contact);
                await contactUnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
            });                             // This line #5
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is likely with [parallel+unitOfWork](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues?q=parallel+unitOfWork). Try without that.

Comment: Found the issue. I have two background worker. And problem occur if both working and at the same time. These workers work with same repository. One of them working in async pattern. And work perfect. But that background worker  become broken with error that I wrote above when second worker begin work. I will investigate more and text the fix.

Comment: Hmm okay. Thanks for getting back.